# How to compute the indexed intersection between two similar pandas columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following list:

```
new_pets = ['Bobcats', 'dog', 'cat', 'turtle', 'monkey', 'goat', 'ferret', 'pig', 'Chipmunks', 'Capybaras', 'Ducks']
```

And the following pandas dataframe:

```
In: df

0   Cats
1   Lizard
2   Dog
3   Baby Ferrets
4   Pig
5   Armadillo
```

How can I get into a new column the elements of `new_pets` which appear in `df`  (*)?:

```
In: df['new_col']

0   True
1   False
2   True
3   True
4   True
5   False
```

From the docs, I noticed that this can be done with [contains()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), so I tried the following:

```
result = df[df['pets'].str.contains(x, case = False) for x in new_pets]
```

However, I am not sure if this is possible. For instance, is it possible to match `Baby Ferrets` with `ferret`, since `Ferrets` is similar to `ferret`?. For that constraint, I tried to use `case=False`, but I am not getting the expected outcome (*). Any idea of how to retrive such strings in a new dataframe?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first join values by `|` (regex [or](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is `|`) and convert all values to lower-case by `lower` - output is in `joined`. Then lowercase all values in column by [`str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) and call [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `joined` for checking if `bobcats` or `dog` or `dog` ... is in column:

```
print (df)
           pets
0          Cats
1        Lizard
2           Dog
3  Baby Ferrets
4           Pig
5     Armadillo

joined = '|'.join(new_pets).lower()

df['new_col'] = df['pets'].str.lower().str.contains(joined)
print (df)
              a new_col
0          Cats    True
1        Lizard   False
2           Dog    True
3  Baby Ferrets    True
4           Pig    True
5     Armadillo   False
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, could you provide an explanation?... I also check that it was possible to use the `'|'.join(new_pets).lower()`. However, I do not understand it...

Comment: Thank you very much jez!

Comment: Here in `df.a.str` `a` refers to what?... Also what about if my `df` has more columns, and I want to just focus in matching a specific one?. Should I do something like: `df['new_col'] = df['sepecific_col'].a.str.lower().str.contains(joined)`?

Comment: sorry, it is column name. If use more as one word use selecting by`[]` :  `df['column 1']`

Comment: So you need `df['new_col'] = df['sepecific_col'].str.lower().str.contains(joined)`

Comment: Basically it's the same idea, specifying the column of interest right?..